# How to include child fxml inside parent fxml

Tags: javafx-2

I need your help with this problem where i want to include child fxml from different package.
I am able to include child.fxml into parent.fxml if both are in same location, but don't know how to add a child.fxml into parent.fxml when both are in diffrent location/package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jewelsea Can you please drop some light on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing to child `FXML` files should be via relative path, from the [FXML docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements) :

> where filename is the name of the FXML file to include. Values that
>   begin with a leading slash character are treated as relative to the
>   classpath. Values with no leading slash are considered relative to the
>   path of the current document.

### Example:

```
org.tarrsalah.includefxml
  |
  |__childview
  |    |_________child.fxml
  |
  |__mainview
       |_________main.fxml
```

**main.fxml**

```
<StackPane id="mainView"  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="org.tarrsalah.includefxml.mainview.MainController">
    <children><fx:include source="../childview/child.fxml"/></children>        
</StackPane>
```

`..` to access to the parent directory,`childview`, and then `child.fxml` .

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am aware of the relative path as you mentioned but i am looking for a solution where i don't have to give a relative path because the same child.fxml file will be in a different location/path on my target system after deployment.

Comment: I think there is no way to specify the child FXML without using relative path.

Comment: Even i think so. But my design needs to create a GUI, say parent.fxml by picking invidual tiny views (child.fxml) accross maven projects.

Comment: the same with maven (relative paths) if you are using [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin), I create an `fxml` directory inside the `resources` folder that contain all my `fxml` files.